# unknown column in on clause with running total

Tags: mysql, sql

Why do I get this error if I uncomment the `LEFT JOIN` ?

```
#1054 - Unknown column 's.id' in 'on clause'
```

The column `s.id` is used multiple times in the query

```
SELECT s.id
     , s.qty
     , s.price_cost
     , @running_total:=@total running_total
     , @total:=@total+s.qty-s.qtyoff total
  FROM stock s
     , (SELECT @running_total:=0, @total:=0) vars
/*LEFT JOIN stockoff o ON o.stockoff_id=s.id*/
 WHERE s.block_id = 5659 
   AND s.type = 2 
   AND s.is_booked = 1 
   AND s.product_id = 18110 
   AND s.time <= 1514678400
 GROUP 
    BY s.id
HAVING running_total <= 0
 ORDER 
    BY s.time DESC
     , s.id DESC
```

Comment: As an aside, there's little point in outer joining a table from which you select no columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that the error is thrown because you are mixing the old-school comma syntax for the join operation with the newer JOIN keyword.

Ditch the comma here

```
FROM stock s, (SELECT @running_total:=0, @total:=0) vars
            ^
```

And replace it with a proper `CROSS JOIN`

```
FROM stock s CROSS JOIN (SELECT @running_total:=0, @total:=0) vars
             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

This is only a guess. I've never researched what happens when we mix the two different syntax in a single SELECT. But there's no good reason to ever mix them. (Maybe the error in the question is sufficient enough reason to *not* to mix them.

The old-school comma syntax is great for backwards compatibility, allowing  legacy SQL to continue to run. But new SQL doesn't have a need to use it.

Comment: It may be just a guess, but it's a correct one. JOIN would work just as well (but CROSS JOIN is clearer).

Comment: @Strawberry: As you correctly point out,  the `CROSS` keyword is entirely optional, and has no effect. MySQL parses `CROSS JOIN`, `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN` identically. My personal preference for specifying `CROSS` keyword here is that it serves to alert (the future reader) that the omission of an `ON` clause is intentional rather than an oversight. Not that portability is much of a concern here, but I think other databases may require the `CROSS` keyword, and garf up an error for a a `JOIN` without an `ON` clause, and I'm loathe to include an `ON 1=1`.